# Why MPI sendrecv get wrong value?

Tags: mpi

I have a physical code with exchange of particles among processors. The strange things happends rare but crushes the program.
So Particle type is transformed to byte array and than exchanged.

`

```
send_bufL = ARRAY_1D(nsendL, Particle);
send_bufR = ARRAY_1D(nsendR, Particle);

for (i = 0; i < nsendL; i++) {
    send_bufL[i] = pstackL[i]->p;
}
for (i = 0; i < nsendR; i++) {
    send_bufR[i] = pstackR[i]->p;
}

MPI_Sendrecv(&nsendR, 1, MPI_INT, procR, 1,
               &nrecvL, 1, MPI_INT, procL, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

MPI_Sendrecv(&nsendL, 1, MPI_INT, procL, 5,
               &nrecvR, 1, MPI_INT, procR, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

recv_bufL = ARRAY_1D(nrecvL, Particle);
recv_bufR = ARRAY_1D(nrecvR, Particle);

MPI_Sendrecv(send_bufR, sizeof(Particle)*nsendR, MPI_BYTE, procR, 7, recv_bufL, 
    sizeof(Particle)*nrecvL, MPI_BYTE, procL, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

for(i = 0; i < nrecvL; i++){
    p = recv_bufL + i;`
```

.
.
.

where

```
char     *Array1D (int, size_t);
#define ARRAY_1D(nx,type) (type   *)Array1D(nx,sizeof(type))
```

so now i have 1 thread, which must send 172 particles to himself and for 160 of them everything is OK, BUT on 161 something happends, buffer become corrupted, or what and all values are messed up, particle's coordinate becomes equal to its speed and etc.

What is the problem?

Comment: 1. Do not send bytes unless you have data that is not int or float or even struct. I wonder if you're running into alignment issues or so. 2. I wonder if your `Particle` object has allocated data in it. That doesn't work.

Comment: Please include a [mcve], the root cause is likely in a snippet you did not share.

Comment: oh.... it will be thousands of code lines